# Create plist file from string

Tags: iphone, objective-c, plist, createfile

I have this string:

```
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Secciones</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>Uid</key>
            <integer>1</integer>
            <key>DateInsert</key>
            <date>3911-04-15T09:20:40Z</date>
            <key>DateModify</key>
            <date>3911-04-15T09:20:40Z</date>
            <key>Name</key>
            <string>Seccion 1</string>
            <key>Description</key>
            <string>Esta es la secciÃ³n 1.</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>Uid</key>
            <integer>2</integer>
            <key>DateInsert</key>
            <date>3911-04-15T09:20:40Z</date>
            <key>DateModify</key>
            <date>3911-04-15T09:20:40Z</date>
            <key>Name</key>
            <string>Seccion 2</string>
            <key>Description</key>
            <string>Esta es la secciÃ³n 2.</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>Uid</key>
            <integer>3</integer>
            <key>DateInsert</key>
            <date>3911-04-15T09:20:40Z</date>
            <key>DateModify</key>
            <date>3911-04-15T09:20:40Z</date>
            <key>Name</key>
            <string>Seccion 3</string>
            <key>Description</key>
            <string>Esta es la secciÃ³n 3.</string>
        </dict>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

I want to create a plist file with this content. I have tried with this:

```
NSString *documentsDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];

NSString *fileName = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"sec.plist"];

NSLog(@"%@",documentsDirectory);
NSLog(@"%@",fileName);

//n is my string 
[n writeToFile:fileName 
    atomically:NO           
      encoding:NSStringEncodingConversionAllowLossy
         error:nil];
```

my console show:

```
2011-09-08 18:26:59.999 Catalogo-V1[1071:207] /Users/.../Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/4.3/Applications/6D96FC16-D6CB-4A03-A0F5-38A0C0C473C7/Documents

2011-09-08 18:27:00.000 Catalogo-V1[1071:207] /Users/.../Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/4.3/Applications/6D96FC16-D6CB-4A03-A0F5-38A0C0C473C7/Documents/sec.plist
```

But don´t create any file.

Comment: So why not pass in an `NSError` pointer to find out what's wrong? :) Declare an NSError *, then pass the address of it to "writeToFile", and `NSLog()` the error object.

Comment: You can't write files to iPhone...

Comment: (That said, I'll sort of give you a hint: the encoding parameter you're using is probably not what you want. You're giving it an "encoding conversion" value, but it wants an actual encoding, like UTF8 or etc. Look at `NSStringEncoding`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Use the `error` parameter of `writeToFile:atomically:encoding:error:` method to retreive the error returned by the call, this will help debug
- Use `NSUTF8StringEncoding` instead of `NSStringEncodingConversionAllowLossy` *(which is not eve an encoding!)*
- Prefer using the [`NSPropertyListSerialization`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSPropertyListSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class to manipulate PLIST files serialization if possible.
- You may find useful to read the [Property List Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/PropertyLists/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000048i) too

Answer (score 0):

`NSStringEncodingConversionAllowLossy` is not an encoding, use something like `NSUTF8StringEncoding` instead.